# Serial monitor can't display float and double values with absolute greater than 4294967040=2^32-2^8

Tags: serial, float

I have the following sketch:

```cpp
void setup() {}

void loop() {
  float af = 4294967040.0;
  float bf = 4294967240.0;
  double ad = 4294967040.0;
  double bd = 4294967040.00001;
  Serial.println(af);
  Serial.println(bf);
  Serial.println(ad);
  Serial.println(bd);
}
```

The values of `af`, `bf`, `ad` and `bd` are way smaller than 3.402823466e38 which is the maximum for float values. The values can still be correctly operated with, but the result on the serial monitor however is `ovf` for `bf` and `bd`.

Why is that?

Comment: Also note that on Unos etc there's no difference between doubles and floats: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/double/

Comment: Related: [Answer on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034906/too-large-const-on-arduino-uno/42040706#42040706)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not the data type, it's the printing routine that sets that limit.  In `Print.cpp`:

```cpp
227   if (isnan(number)) return print("nan");
228   if (isinf(number)) return print("inf");
229   if (number > 4294967040.0) return print ("ovf");  // constant determined empirically
230   if (number <-4294967040.0) return print ("ovf");  // constant determined empirically
```

Don't ask why...

Comment: That's bizarre, it's not even the (quite) max unsigned int value. Might try a version w/o that and see what happens.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know. It was a surprise to me too...

Comment: print does not produce an exponent format, so there must be a reasonable limit somewhere. Maybe they took the mantissa size ? surprise, yes indeed. **Thanks for bringing this to our attention,**

Comment: 4294967040.0 (float)  is 0x4f7fffff  => (Sign) 0  (Exponent) 10011110 (Mantissa) 11111111111111111111111

Comment: Looks like it's a guard for [`unsigned long int_part = (unsigned long)number;`](https://github.com/sparkfun/Arduino_Boards/blob/master/sparkfun/samd/cores/LilyMini/Print.cpp).  Since `number` can be larger than an `unsigned long` can hold, the explicit-cast, `(unsigned long)number`, probably threw an error or something, around that value.  Since the value was **"_determined empirically_"**, it may've been a bit stricter than necessary.  Guessing it could've been as high as 2^32-1 (whereas it's actually just 2^32-256).